# How do I create a single JAR file to move specific files in a folder to another directory?

Tags: java, file, jar, directory, exe

I created a Java program which basically moves all files within a specific "test" folder to a completely different and specific directory on the computer. How can I package the "test" folder, and both the java and class files into a single runnable JAR file?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File sourceFolder = new File("test");
        String dataFolder = System.getenv("APPDATA");

        File destinationFolder = new File(dataFolder + "\\testing");

        copyFolder(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
    }
    private static void copyFolder(File sourceFolder, File destinationFolder) throws IOException
    {
        if (sourceFolder.isDirectory()) 
        {
            if (!destinationFolder.exists()) 
            {
                destinationFolder.mkdir();
            }

            String files[] = sourceFolder.list();

            for (String file : files) 
            {
                File srcFile = new File(sourceFolder, file);
                File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, file);
                copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File installed successfully","Title",1);
        }
        else
        {
            Files.copy(sourceFolder.toPath(), destinationFolder.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error I get when I move the test folder:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: test
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:98)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:283)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1298)
        at Test.copyFolder(test.java:39)
        at Test.main(test.java:16)
```

Comment: If you want to create a .jar file in code, use [JarOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html).  If you want to do it on the command line, see [the jar command reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html).  Note that there are build tools which can do this work with just a few lines in a build file, like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org).

Comment: I have done it on command line and the jar file works fine, however, whenever I move the test folder, or if I move the whole jar file it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please be more specific than “it doesn’t work.”  How can you tell it doesn’t work?  Describe your actions with enough detail that others can try it.  If you’re getting an exception, edit your question and show the entire stack trace of that exception.

Comment: Once the jar file is moved simply nothing happens when I double click it, but if the test folder is in the same directory of the jar file it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: If a .jar file doesn’t work when double clicked, you should observe the actual output of the program by running it in a command window, using something like `java -jar C:\Users\josefk\projects\MyProgram.jar`.